# save byte array of image in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on the project using backend as Mongoose, nodejs and express. The front end is an android application.The API is created using Mongoose, nodejs and express, android application is using my APIs to get and set data. Now I have to create one post API '/uploadImage', in such a way that android app will pass only 'byte array' of an image as post data to '/uploadImage'. I have to parse this byte array of image and save image to one directory.

Code Which i have tried to upload file using formidable:

```
exports.uploadFile = function(req, res) {
    var dirpath = config.root + '/files/Documents/';
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function(err, data, files) {
        fs.readFile(files.file.path, function(err, data) {
            var newPath = dirpath + files.file.name;
            fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function(err) {
                if (!err) {
                    var filePath = '/files/Documents/' + files.file.name;
                    res.send(filePath);
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

This is working fine. In this I am getting file not byte array.So I am able to save file into respective directory.I don't have any idea how it will work with byte array.

Comment: so, what did you try?

Comment: I have used formidable to parse file and also I successfully saved simple file to directory. But I am unable to parse and store image using byte array.

Comment: :) I mean could you, please, post your code here?

Comment: edited question with code.

Comment: You can have your Android client upload the image via a `multipart/form-data` request and it should work fine with the code you have posted. What specifically do you mean by "byte array" and why is it a requirement?

Comment: It is android client's requirement they have told me that they can not send me image as a file they can only send me an bytearray of an image. And by bytearray i dont have specific meaning, it is just image data in bytes. Anyways @simon and Andrew thanks for your response.I have solved this issue with one post. :)

Comment: @zulekha even I am stuck with same problem. Can you please tell the link of the post from where you found solution, or guide me on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in following way.

```
 var rawImg = req.body.imageByteArray,
    base64Data = rawImg.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ''),
    dirpath = config.root + '/files/Documents/',
    imageName = req.body.filename + '.png',
    imageLocation = dirpath + imageName;
  fs.writeFile(imageLocation, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {});
```